# Adding 10 on to each value in a mysql query

Tags: sql, mysqli

I want to create a query that will add 10 to all the values, e.g. take the table below

```
name   values
A      10
B      20
C      30

$qry = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table")
```

I could do it through php, but that could create a lot of extra sql calls

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry) {
   $new_value = $row['values']+10;
   $name = $row['name'];
   $qry2 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE table SET values=$new_value WHERE name='$name'");
 }
```

But that could be a lot of sql queries. How can we just update all the values in the table in one query?

Comment: Hint:  No `where` clause if you want to update all the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just update the value with a single query:

```sql
UPDATE table SET values = values + 10;
```

And wrapped in PHP:

```php
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE table SET values = values + 10");
```

This will update all rows in the table. If you want to limit the query, just add a where clause for the fields that should be included in the subset:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE table SET values = values + 10 WHERE name='$name'");
```

However, in this solution as well as your approach, it's open for SQL Injection. You should use prepared statements to avoid this type of unwanted behavior.

Comment: and you could add where clause on to that?

Comment: @Source Yes, it's still possible to use a `WHERE` statement in the query.